# Please explain how these hooks work

Tags: hooks, actions

I have read about hooks and actions and I know that when we see `do_action('some_hook')` it means that somewhere `add_action('some_hook', function() {...});` or function `some_hook()` exists in a theme's `functions.php`.

But what is it?! :

From **woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php** line #943:

```
public function process_checkout() {
    try {
        /////////////
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_process' ); <----!!!

        if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
            throw new Exception( sprintf( __( 'Sorry, your session has expired. <a href="%s" class="wc-backward">Return to shop</a>', 'woocommerce' ), esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ) );
        }

        do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process' ); <-----!!!
```

I can't find `woocommerce_checkout_process` and `woocommerce_before_checkout_process` anywhere in files! What do they do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible for action hooks to be provided without being used, which is what's happening here.

`woocommerce_before_checkout_process` and `woocommerce_checkout_process` are hooks provided by WooCommerce, but WooCommerce does not itself attach callback functions to either of these hooks. They are provided to allow plugins and themes to run code at the time that the respective hooks are triggered.

If you'd like to attach a function to the `woocommerce_checkout_process` hook (for example), you'd add the following code to your theme or plugin:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wpse_woocommerce_checkout_process' );
function wpse_woocommerce_checkout_process() {
    // Do something...
}
```

This code will run when the line calling `do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process' );` in WooCommerce is executed.

Comment: I added an example of how to attach a callback function. You don't call `do_action` in your code (unless you are defining your own hook which is not the case here). You'd use `add_action()`.